# Add to cart in localhost doesn't work in IE, Why?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, magento-enterprise, checkout, cart

I have my development site in

```
http://localhost/mydevsite/
```

Everything is working fine, until I tested it in IE browser. When I click add to cart button (no changes made to this functionality), it gets redirected to cart page, but the cart is empty.

In other browsers, it is working fine. I use IE 10, also tested in IE9, IE8, IE7 (checked using the Browser Mode option). The problem prevails. I checked with both Magento CE and EE.

Is there a problem with IE settings, so that localhost websites doesn't hold cookies or something like that? Can anyone help me on this?

EDIT:
sorry I forgot to mention, I don't have permissions to edit hosts file, otherwise I could have created a virtual domain.
If other browsers can add products to cart, why not IE? I remember I have used loclhost in IE sometime back and it worked.

Comment: as suggested by Marius, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639199/localhost-to-127-0-0-1-as-default) gives me good fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `localhost` as you host. For some reasons Magento needs a dot `.` in the host in order to be able to store cookies. Use `127.0.0.1` or add to `hosts` something like

```
magento.local    127.0.0.1
```

and use `magento.local` as your host.
You will need to change the base_url in `core_config_data` in order to make it work.
**[EDIT]**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639199/localhost-to-127-0-0-1-as-default) may offer a solution. It involves changing the way that the cookies are validated.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, I don't have permissions to edit hosts file, otherwise I could have created a virtual domain. If other browsers can add products to cart, why not IE? I remember I have used loclhost in IE sometime back and it worked.

Comment: I always had problems when using `localhost` for version 1.2+. I usually work with `127.0.0.1` and it works great. You can also check the IE settings. Maybe you are not allowed to set cookies. Edit: Check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639199/localhost-to-127-0-0-1-as-default

Comment: as suggested by Marius, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639199/localhost-to-127-0-0-1-as-default) gives me good fix

Comment: Great. I added it to the answer also.